# What is the meaning of the word "Append"

Tags: c#

I'm in the middle in studying some code and I encountered this word "Append" and I don't understand what it does.

#### Code:

```
public static void appendData(string data)
    {
        if (isRecording) sb.Append(data + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

What does append mean?

Comment: Listen, you are going to start looking at contributing a bit and doing some more homework, perhaps reading a few books.

Comment: Doesn't your IDE (you might call this Visual Studio...) tell you what Append means if you hover over it. This could open a few doors.

Comment: I am voting to close this, not that I have anything against how to move a turtle, this question just does not make sense

Comment: The question makes sense if he's asking as someone with low English skills, and hasn't heard the word "Append" before. Face it, it's not a word we use in ordinary conversation (at least, not in the US).

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was not a more appropriate resource for looking up one word in another language.

Comment: There is, and I included that in my answer. His question was: what does append mean in this code, because I'm not familiar with the word. He needed to know what it meant in the code, and then also needed to know it was a common English word, and not some technical term.

Comment: @sam: I'm reading some books. But I haven't encountered this word "Append" yet while learning c#. 
And I've also tried searching google and it only display questions also about "Append". 
Listen, if I've knew the answer I wont post this question here!

Comment: My question was not about the meaning of append in general term, but the function of it in the code given.

Comment: @tintincute: We're not setting to out to ridicule anyone here, maybe you are getting hung up on the meaning of the word in it's C# context too much. With an object like sb the methods such as Append are named by whoever wrote them, there is no great meaning and the purpose of the method should be conveyed in it's comments, then it will appear when you hover. Have a word with your boss and get him/her to comment the appendData method so you can know what it does, just like the team that did StringBuilder did with theirs. Peace :)

Comment: Oh, and a public method should always start with a captial (upper case) letter.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson: You're quite right. Everything just seems new to me because I have been learning C# in just 2 months and I'm encoutering these words which I haven't learned yet. It's just difficult to integrate especially if you don't have any programming experience like me. 
what my boss is doing now, he's trying to correct an old code which was written by somebody. and the old code doesn't have any comments on it.now i'm working on the said code,with a little idea about c#

Comment: you mean: it should be like this:

"public static void AppendData(string data)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer from ChrisF is correct as far as StringBuilder.Append is concerned.

In general, the word "Append" means "to add to the end of". See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/append.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that `sb` is of type `StringBuilder`.

`Append()` adds the supplied string to the end of the string being built in the `StringBuilder` variable.

Comment: Thanks ChrisF so that means StringBuilder is another Data type?
I haven't encountered that yet as data type. just to make sure.
Thanks

Comment: StringBuilder is a reference type. Search for it in your IDEs help or online here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This is quite simple. Then code above is simply "adding" or "appending" the variables/text supplied within the brackets to the variable "sb".

Append can be found as part of the `System.Text.StringBuilder` class which I believe is being used above.

More info can be found following this link: [`StringBuilder` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Happy coding!

Comment: this is great input chinna. thanks:-) i'll take note of that

Answer (score 3):

I would point out that the "right" way to do that bit of code is:

```
public static void appendData(string data)
    {
        if (isRecording) 
            {
                sb.Append(data);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
    }
```

Append is doing the same job as string1 + string2 but it is doing it in a much more efficient manner. Look up "Immutable Strings C#" for some more details if you need them.

Comment: The "right" way is probably AppendLine ...

Comment: Actually a better way would be to use AppendLine.

Comment: It isn't much more efficient, the breakover occurs when you concat three or more strings in a big loop. Your's is better to debug. :)

Comment: @Sam- you beat me to it!

Comment: thanks somori for additional input. 
what i would like to know is what is the function of "Append" here in the code and what does it do.
i know it's good if the code is written nicely, but i think it's not the issue here at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It will add the string representation of the object to end of the string builder instance. It basically calls the .ToString() method of whatever object you pass in and concatenates it to the end of the internal string being build up.

See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.append.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio put your cursor on the word Append and Press F1, you'll probably see [something like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.append.aspx). If you are considering refactoring this and assuming it is using a StringBuilder, you might also want to read about [AppendLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline.aspx).

Comment: hi Richard thanks. yes I'm using VS I tried pointing my cursor to the word Append and press F1, but nothing happened. I tried searching in google just by typing append c# and I'm getting no explanations. Google displays only questions about "append". I don't know maybe I'm not searching it properly.
But thanks for your input

Comment: Probably something to do with your setup. Have a look at this- http://blogs.msdn.com/randalli/archive/2006/07/28/sharepoint-development-tip-getting-context-sensitive-f1-help-directly-from-the-msdn-library.aspx it might help.